# Probability of getting your hat back

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Stuck on this question and wondering if I could get some help.

Suppose n people go to a party and leave their hats at the door.
At the end of the party, each person picks
up a hat at random.
Assume each assignment of hats to persons is equally likely.

What is the expected
number of people that get their own hats back?

---

So what I was thinking is that the first person who picks up a hat will pick their own hat with a prob of $\frac{1}{n}$. The second would have prob $\frac{1}{n-1}$ etc.. I'm not convinced however that this is the right way to go about the question.

Comment: $1$ setup out of $n!$ will be profitable. Not a very large chance.

Comment: Wait they now get to pick their own hate? Is that really wise to let them do that?

Comment: You were right in being unconvinced.  The second only has probability $\frac{1}{n-1}$ if the first hasn't picked up the second's hat; otherwise, the second's probability is $0$.  The probability of the first not picking up the hat of the second is $\frac{n-1}{n}$.  When you take that into account, you find that the probability of the second going home wearing the right hat is again $\frac{1}{n}$.  The argument extends to all the other people claiming their hats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sort of problem is a lot easier with indicator variables.  Let $X_i$ be the indicator variable for the event "the $i^{th}$ person gets their hat back".  Then, of course, $$E[X_i]=\frac 1n$$

By the Linearity of Expectations  the answer you seek is $$E\left[\sum X_i\right]=\sum E[X_i]=n\times \frac 1n = 1$$